# Integrating jPCT with Vuforia / QCAR SDK

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, qcar-sdk, jpct

I have problem using Vuforia with jPCT.

I have successfully passed the `modelViewMatrix` from Vuforia native code

```java
QCAR::Matrix44F modelViewMatrix =  QCAR::Tool::convertPose2GLMatrix(imageResult->getPose())
```

to Java.

And then I try to set the camera matrix of jPCT.

```java
public void setCameraMatrix(float[] modelViewMatrixFromVuforia) {

        float x = modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[12];
        float y = modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[13];
        float z = modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[14];

        modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[12] = 0;
        modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[13] = 0;
        modelViewMatrixFromVuforia[14] = 0;

        Matrix cameraMatrix = new Matrix();
        cameraMatrix.setDump(modelViewMatrixFromVuforia);

        cameraMatrix = cameraMatrix.invert();
        camera.setBack(cameraMatrix);
        camera.setPosition(x, y, z);
    }
```

But the 3D Object is not being tracked properly. What have I missed?

Answer (score 4):

I'm using this and it works perfectly:

```java
private Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
...

mMatrix.setDump(modelViewMatrixFromVuforia); // float[16] sent from native code
mCamera.setBack(mMatrix);
```

But you have to rotate the matrix 180 degree around X axis **before** you send it to Java in order to match the coordinate system from Vuforia to jPCT.

Do the rotation in native codes as follows:

```
SampleUtils::rotatePoseMatrix(180.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, &modelViewMatrix.data[0]);
```

Comment: I have added cameraMatrix.rotateX((float)Math.PI) but it does not work. Do you mind share your code which is working? Thanks.